# Need help restoring a locked folder within the recycle bin

Tags: windows, file-permissions, restore, recycle-bin, locked-files

I've got a crucial folder in my recycle bin that I need to restore but I can't get it out due to it being locked!

I tried using IOBit Unlocker but it doesn't support files that are in the recycle bin. Using the command prompt as an administrator also doesn't work and gives me the message "Access is denied". So, I've run out of options and could really use some help.